# How to set priority to the notification using HMS Push Kit?

Tags: push-notification, huawei-mobile-services

When I'm sending the push notification, I want to set the priority to it.
I have check the reference link:
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-3-References/push-server-send#BadgeNotification

But I  couldn't find exactly where to set priority.

I'm using this JSON format:

```
{
"validate_only": false,
"message": {
"notification": {
"title": "Big News",
"body": "This is a Big News!"
},
"android": {
"notification": {
"title": "Noti in Noti title",
"body": "Noti in Noti body",
"click_action": {
"type": 1,
"intent": "#Intent;compo=com.rvr/.Activity;S.W=U;end"
}
}
},
"token":  ["AAWWHI94sgUR2RU5_P1ZptUiwLq7W8XWJO2LxaAPuXw4_HOJFXnBlN-q5_3bwlxVW_SHeDPx_s5bWW-9DjtWZsvcm9CwXe1FHJg0u-D2pcQPcb3sTxDTJeiwEb9WBPl_9w"]
}
}
```

Please help me by providing some reference.

Answer (score 1):

The posted reference link is for the old HMS version 3 document.  Please refer to the [latest document](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/https-send-api-0000001050986197-V5).

Under section AndroidConfig Structure, there is an Urgency parameter for setting the message delivery priority:

[image]

Under the AndroidNotification Structure section, there is an Importance parameter to set the message notification priority.

[image]

Comment: Seems like this is not applicable anymore. In [current version](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References/https-send-api-0000001050986197) of the doc, there is no `urgency` field and no `HIGH` option for the `importance` field.